# Stanford NER Features

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am currently trying to use the Stanford NER system and I am trying to see what features can be extracted through setting of the flags in a properties file. It seems that the features documented at http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html are not comprehensive. For example, all the feature flags related to dist similarity and clustering are not included (e.g. useDistSim, etc.). Is there a more complete list of all the features and corresponding flags that is available somewhere?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

At present, no. You need to look through the source code....

Comment: Can you please specify the files of source code where this information could be found?

Comment: The two relevant classes are SeqClassifierFlags and (especially) NERFeatureFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Feature of NER is declare in  properties file.
You can find more information from [NER FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml), question 2.