# Stanford NERFeatureFactory description

Tags: stanford-nlp

Do you know where can I find more details on the description of the Stanford NERFeatureFactory?

I read the one at: https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html
but I do not understand them all (and some have no description).

For example:usePrev, 
useWordPairs,
conjoinShapeNGrams,
useSum, ...
or
(pw,c) (t,c)

There was a [similar question 2 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431094/stanford-ner-features) ago without a better description. I was wondering if something new came out since then.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the source code of NERFeatureFactory you can see what is going on.

The source code is available here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.java

For example, `useWordPairs` creates features for the word under consideration and the previous/next word.  You can see this in the code starting on line 1062...

As an example, consider the features for the word `New` in this text `...from New York...`...the useWordPairs feature produces the features `New-from-W-PW` and `New-York-W-NW`

A lot of the features have descriptions in that file as well.

It's helpful to look through the code and see what is being produced.  For instance the `conjoinShapeNGrams` feature is producing features that attach the overall shape of the word and substrings of the word.  You can see fully what is going on by looking at the code.

As an example of `conjoinShapeNGrams`, consider the name `Wordsworth` which would get features like `worth-Xxxxxxxxxx-CNGram-CS` , `Words-Xxxxxxxxxx-CNGram-CS`, etc...

This feature is capturing the presence of a certain substring and word shape together.

(pw, c) refers to "previous word" and "current word", which is linked to the usePrev flag

(t, c) refers to "part of speech tag" and "current word", which is linked to the useTags flag

It doesn't look like `useSum` does anything anymore...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
I was able to see which features were used by saving them using the property: "printFeatures=True", which also helped.

Where in the code can I see the model that uses those features? 

I'm also interested in understanding how multiple features for a single word are handled.

Thanks